# Problems with python BST insert

Tags: python, binary-tree

I can't figure out the how to do _inserthelp function in the code below. Everything else seems to be working pretty well... It currently does not work as expected. The current function can add the first node (the root) and also the second node, which would be root.left. After that it doesn't work.

Assignment description:

In this exercise, you are given an implementation of a binary search tree.
The class `BST`, found in the exercise package, contains the methods
`insert` and `find` which can be used for inserting and finding key-value
pairs.
These methods utilize two recursive helper methods `_inserthelp` and
`_findhelp` to work properly.
Your task is to implement these helper methods.
In addition, you should implement the method `_visit_inorder` which returns
an iterator yielding the nodes of the tree in inorder.
You do not need to change the code outside these 3 methods to get full
points.
'''

Code:

class BSTNode:

```
def __init__(self, key, value=None):
    self.key = key
    self.value = value
    self.left = None
    self.right = None

def height(self):
    """Return the height of this node."""
    left_height = 1 + self.left.height() if self.left else 0
    right_height = 1 + self.right.height() if self.right else 0
    return max(left_height, right_height)

def __repr__(self):
    return "<BSTNode: key={!r}, value={!r}, id={}>".format(self.key, self.value, id(self))
```

class BSTException(Exception):

```
pass
```

class BST:

```
def __init__(self, NodeClass=BSTNode):
    self.BSTNode = NodeClass
    self.root = None
    self.nodes = 0
    #​​‌​‌​​‌‌‌​​‌​ Updated after each call to insert
    self.newest_node = None

def find(self, find_key):
    """Return node with key find_key if it exists. If not, return None. """
    return self._findhelp(self.root, find_key)

def insert(self, new_key, value=None):
    """Insert a new node with key new_key into this BST,
    increase node count by one and return the inserted node."""

    if self.find(new_key) is not None:
        raise KeyError("This BST already contains key {0!r}".format(new_key))

    if self.root == None:
        self.root = self._inserthelp(self.root, new_key, value)
        self.newest_node = self.root
    else:
        self.newest_node = self._inserthelp(self.newest_node, new_key,value)
    
    self.nodes += 1

    return self.newest_node

def height(self):
    """Return the height of this tree."""
    return self.root.height() if self.root else -1

def __iter__(self):
    """Return an iterator of the keys of this tree in sorted order."""
    for node in self._visit_inorder(self.root):
        yield node.key

def __len__(self):
    return self.nodes


#​​‌​‌​​‌‌‌​​‌​ Implement the methods below.

def _findhelp(self, node, find_key):
    """Starting from node, search for node with key find_key and return that node.
    If no node with key find_key exists, return None."""
    inorderlist = self._visit_inorder(node)
    for _node in inorderlist:
        if _node is None or find_key == _node.key:
            return _node
            #​​‌​‌​​‌‌‌​​‌​ End search
    
    return None
    #​​‌​‌​​‌‌‌​​‌​ Implement functionality to recursively choose the next node

def _inserthelp(self, node, new_key, value):
    """Starting from node, find an empty spot for the new node and
    insert it into this BST."""

    if node is None:
            self.newest_node = BSTNode(new_key,value)
    else:
        # Do level order traversal until we find 
        # an empty place. 
        tree = []
        tree.append(node)
        node = tree[0]
        tree.pop()
        while len(tree):
            if (not node.left):
                node.left = BSTNode(new_key,value)
                self.newest_node = BSTNode(new_key,value)
                break
            else:
                tree.append(node.left) 
    
            if (not node.right):
                node.right = BSTNode(new_key,value)
                self.newest_node = BSTNode(new_key,value)
                break
            else:
                tree.append(node.right)

    return self.newest_node


def _visit_inorder(self, starting_node):

    def inorder(node,indorderlist):
        if node is None:
            return
        else:
            inorder(node.left, inorderlist)
            indorderlist.append(node)
            inorder(node.right, inorderlist)


    inorderlist = []
    inorder(starting_node, inorderlist)
    return inorderlist
```

Tester:

class Test1BSTNode(unittest.TestCase):

```
def test1_empty_node_init(self):
    """BSTNodes are initialized with key, value, left and right instance variables. (0p)"""
    node = BSTNode(1)
    self.assertEqual(node.key, 1)
    self.assertIsNone(node.value)
    self.assertIsNone(node.left)
    self.assertIsNone(node.right)
    node = BSTNode(1, 'a')
    self.assertEqual(node.value, 'a')

def test2_single_node_height(self):
    """The height of a BSTNode with no children is 0. (0p)"""
    node = BSTNode(1)
    self.assertEqual(node.height(), 0)

def test3_node_height_one_child(self):
    """The height of a BSTNode with one child is 1 and the height of that child is 0. (0p)"""
    node = BSTNode(1)
    node.left = BSTNode(2)
    self.assertEqual(node.height(), 1)
    self.assertEqual(node.left.height(), 0)

def test4_node_height_uneven_subtrees(self):
    """The height of a BSTNode with subtrees of uneven heights is the height of the taller subtree plus one. (0p)"""
    node = BSTNode(1)
    node.left = BSTNode(2)
    node.left.left = BSTNode(3)
    self.assertEqual(
        node.left.height(),
        1,
        "Expected the height of a node with one child, which is a leaf, to be 1 but it was not."
    )
    node.right = BSTNode(4)
    self.assertEqual(
        node.right.height(),
        0,
        "Expected the height of a leaf to be 0 but it was not."
    )
    self.assertEqual(
        node.height(),
        node.left.height()+1,
        "Expected the height of a node with two children, left and right, of which right is a leaf and left has one child, which is a leaf, to be the height of left plus one but it was not."
    )
```

class Test2EmptyBST(unittest.TestCase):

```
def setUp(self):
    self.tree = BST()

def test1_bst_init_node_class(self):
    """BSTs are initialized with a node class. (0p)."""
    self.assertIs(
        self.tree.BSTNode,
        BSTNode,
        "When no node class is specified, the BST should use the class BSTNode as the node class."
    )

def test2_empty_size(self):
    """An empty BST has a size equal to zero. (0p)"""
    tree_size = len(self.tree)
    self.assertEqual(
        0,
        tree_size,
        "Calling len on a tree containing no nodes should return 0, not {}"
        .format(tree_size)
    )

def test3_empty_find(self):
    """Searching for a key in an empty BST returns None. (0p)"""
    self.assertIsNone(
        self.tree.find(1),
        "Calling find in an empty BST should return None."
    )

def test4_empty_insert(self):
    """Calling insert on an empty tree returns the inserted node and adds it to the tree. (0p)"""
    new_key = 1
    new_value = "value"

    inserted_node = self.tree.insert(new_key, new_value)
    self.assertIsInstance(
        inserted_node,
        BSTNode,
        "tree.insert should return an instance of BSTNode, not {0!r}."
        .format(inserted_node)
    )
    self.assertEqual(
        inserted_node.key,
        new_key,
        "Calling tree.insert({0}, {1}) should return a node with the key {0}, not {2}."
        .format(new_key, new_value, inserted_node.key)
    )
    self.assertIs(
        inserted_node.value,
        new_value,
        "Calling tree.insert({0}, {1}) should return a node with the value {1}, not {2}."
        .format(new_key, new_value, inserted_node.value)
    )

    tree_size = len(self.tree)
    self.assertEqual(
        tree_size,
        1,
        "Calling len on a tree containing one key should return 1, not {}"
        .format(tree_size)
    )

def test5_find_one(self):
    """Calling find for a node which exists should return that node. (1p)"""
    node = BSTNode(2)
    node.left = BSTNode(1)
    node.right = BSTNode(3)
    self.tree.root = node

    for node in (node, node.left, node.right):
        found_node = self.tree.find(node.key)
        self.assertIs(
            found_node,
            node,
            "If {0!r} exists in tree, calling tree.find({1}) should return that node, not {2!r}"
            .format(node, node.key, found_node)
        )
```

class Test3TenNodesBST(unittest.TestCase):

```
def setUp(self):
    self.tree = BST()
    self.keys = random.sample(range(1, 11), 10)

def test1_insert_ten_nodes(self):
    """Inserting ten nodes into a BST should increase its size by ten. (1p)"""
    for key in self.keys:
        inserted_node = self.tree.insert(key)
        self.assertIsInstance(
            inserted_node,
            BSTNode,
            "tree.insert should return an instance of BSTNode, not {0!r}."
            .format(inserted_node)
        )
        self.assertEqual(
            inserted_node.key,
            key,
            "Calling tree.insert({0}) should return a node with the key {0}, not {1}."
            .format(key, inserted_node.key)
        )

    correct_size = len(self.keys)
    returned_size = len(self.tree)

    self.assertEqual(
        correct_size,
        returned_size,
        "Calling len on a tree with {0} nodes should return {0}, not {1}"
        .format(correct_size, returned_size)
    )


def test2_find_ten_nodes(self):
    """All keys which have been inserted should be found by the find method. (1p)"""
    for key in self.keys:
        self.tree.insert(key)

    for key in self.keys:
        returned_node = self.tree.find(key)
        self.assertIsNotNone(
            returned_node,
            "Calling find for an existing key {0} should return the node holding the key, not None"
            .format(key)
        )
        self.assertEqual(
            returned_node.key,
            key,
            "Calling find for an existing key {0} should return the node holding the key, not {1!r}."
            .format(key, returned_node)
        )
```

class Test4BSTProperty(unittest.TestCase):

```
def setUp(self):
    self.tree = BST()

def test1_smaller_values_go_left(self):
    """Adding values in sorted descending order creates internal nodes with only left children. (1p)"""
    #​​‌​‌​​‌‌‌​​‌​ Insert nodes with keys 10, 9, 8, ... , 1
    for key in range(10, 0, -1):
        self.tree.insert(key)

    #​​‌​‌​​‌‌‌​​‌​ Starting from the root, traverse down towards the leaf, checking
    #​​‌​‌​​‌‌‌​​‌​ both children of each node
    node = self.tree.root
    for key in range(10, 1, -1):
        self.assertEqual(
            key,
            node.key,
            "After inserting keys in range 10, 9, ... , 2, 1 and then iterating in that range, expected the keys of all the left nodes starting from the root follow this sequence, but a node {0} with the key {1} was found."
            .format(node, node.key)
        )
        #​​‌​‌​​‌‌‌​​‌​ There should not be a right child
        self.assertIsNone(
            node.right,
            "Adding keys in order 10, 9, .. , 2, 1 should not create nodes with right children, but a node {0} with a right child {1} was found."
            .format(node, node.right)
        )
        #​​‌​‌​​‌‌‌​​‌​ There should be a left child
        self.assertIsNotNone(
            node.left,
            "Adding keys in order 10, 9, .. , 2, 1 should only create nodes with left children, but a node {0} with no left child was found."
            .format(node)
        )
        #​​‌​‌​​‌‌‌​​‌​ Go left to next node
        node = node.left

    #​​‌​‌​​‌‌‌​​‌​ The last node is a leaf
    self.assertIsNone(
        node.left,
        "After adding nodes in range 10, 9, ... , 2, 1, the node with key 1 should be a leaf, but it had a left child {0}."
        .format(node.left)
    )
    self.assertIsNone(
        node.right,
        "After adding nodes in range 10, 9, ... , 1, the node with key 1 should be a leaf, but it had a right child {0}."
        .format(node.right)
    )


def test2_larger_values_go_right(self):
    """Adding values in sorted ascending order creates internal nodes with only right children. (1p)"""
    #​​‌​‌​​‌‌‌​​‌​ Insert nodes with keys 1, 2, ... , 10
    for key in range(1, 11):
        self.tree.insert(key)

    #​​‌​‌​​‌‌‌​​‌​ Starting from the root, traverse down towards the leaf, checking
    #​​‌​‌​​‌‌‌​​‌​ both children of each node
    node = self.tree.root
    for key in range(1, 10):
        self.assertEqual(
            key,
            node.key,
            "After inserting keys in range 1, 2, ... , 9, 10 and then iterating in that range, expected the keys of all the right nodes starting from the root to follow this sequence, but a node {0} with the key {1} was found."
            .format(node, node.key)
        )
        #​​‌​‌​​‌‌‌​​‌​ There should not be a left child
        self.assertIsNone(
            node.left,
            "Adding keys in order 1, 2, ... , 9, 10 should not create nodes with left children, but a node {0} with a left child {1} was found."
            .format(node, node.left)
        )
        #​​‌​‌​​‌‌‌​​‌​ There should be a right child
        self.assertIsNotNone(
            node.right,
            "Adding keys in order 1, 2, ... , 9, 10 should only create nodes with right children, but a node {0} with no right child was found."
            .format(node)
        )
        #​​‌​‌​​‌‌‌​​‌​ Go right to the next node
        node = node.right

    #​​‌​‌​​‌‌‌​​‌​ The last node is a leaf
    self.assertIsNone(
        node.left,
        "After adding nodes in range 1, 2, ... , 9, 10, the node with key 10 should be a leaf, but it had a left child {0}."
        .format(node.left)
    )
    self.assertIsNone(
        node.right,
        "After adding nodes in range 1, 2, ... , 9, 10, the node with key 10 should be a leaf, but it had a left child {0}."
        .format(node.right)
    )


def test3_inorder_traversal(self):
    """An inorder traversal visits all nodes in the tree. (1p)"""
    keys = random.sample(range(100), 20)
    inserted = set(self.tree.insert(key) for key in keys)
    visited = set(self.tree._visit_inorder(self.tree.root))

    self.assertSetEqual(
        visited,
        inserted,
        "An inorder traversal should return all nodes which have been added to the tree.\n" +
        "_visit_inorder did not visit the nodes seen above although they were inserted into the tree."
    )


def test4_iter_tree_keys(self):
    """Iterating the tree yields the keys of the tree in sorted ascending order. (1p)"""
    keys = random.sample(range(100), 20)
    for key in keys:
        self.tree.insert(key)

    #​​‌​‌​​‌‌‌​​‌​ Shorter form of [key for key in self.tree]
    #​​‌​‌​​‌‌‌​​‌​ (which is possible because the class BST implements the method __iter__)
    visited = list(self.tree)
    #​​‌​‌​​‌‌‌​​‌​ The returned values should be in sorted ascending order
    correct_order = sorted(keys)

    self.assertListEqual(
        visited,
        correct_order,
        "Calling __iter__ should return an iterator of the keys of the BST in sorted ascending order.\n" +
        "Note: the traversal method should not care in what order the nodes appear, if the insert method is implemented correctly, an inorder traversal will yield the keys in sorted order."
    )


def test5_height_complete_tree(self):
    """The height of a complete tree with n nodes is log_2(n+1) - 1. (1p)"""
    #​​‌​‌​​‌‌‌​​‌​ Add keys so they form a complete tree
    keys = [50, 25, 75, 20, 30, 70, 80]
    for key in keys:
        self.tree.insert(key)

    tree_size = len(self.tree)
    added_count = len(keys)
    self.assertEqual(
        tree_size,
        added_count,
        "Adding {0} keys to an initially empty tree, calling len on the tree should return {0}, not {1}."
        .format(added_count, tree_size)
    )

    #​​‌​‌​​‌‌‌​​‌​ math.log returns float
    self.assertAlmostEqual(
        float(self.tree.height()),
        math.log(len(keys) + 1, 2) - 1,
    )
```

if **name** == '**main**':
unittest.main(verbosity=2)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very big and hard to digest, however I think that, you are trying to insert new key into the last entry. But this is not always valid. Suppose you have this, BST,

```
  5
 / \
3   7
```

Here 5,3 and 7 are inserted one after another. So the last entry here is 7. So, if you want to insert 4 here, you will have to insert it in 3, not into 7 which is the last entry. So by your method it won't work.

So, the solution is insert it in the root, which will look like,

```
      5
     / \
    3   7
     \
      4
```

But I am still not 100% sure if it is the problem in your code. For me, it's big uncommented code to digest.